# Did Lucas intend to continue the story beyond Episode VI?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, george-lucas

*The Return of the Jedi* concludes with the Emperor's death at Vader's hands, the Force being balanced and the prophecy being fulfilled. The galaxy was at peace -- the events conclude, and Luke and Leia are reunited, concluding their relationship arc.

The prequels add backstory to it, but the conclusion is still at the end of *Jedi*. However, with the release of *The Force Awakens* it becomes possible that there will always be *another* episode. Did Lucas have a strong idea of what he wanted the conclusion to be -- of what he considered the "story" (I.e., Vader's arc, concluding with the death of the Emperor) and whether he intended it to continue past Episode VI?

To clarify, I mean what Lucas intended as the 'main story' -- that is, not extended universe.

Comment: Inspired by this question: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/113310/should-star-wars-have-ended-after-return-of-the-jedi

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Before the Disney canon-cull, there was a series of works in other media (books, comics etc..) that continued the story post *Return of the Jedi*, but none of that was an **Episode**, in the way that *The Force Awakens* is labelled.

Lucas has been varied (to say the least) on what he saw *Star Wars* as. He said this around the time of the *The Clone Wars* animated film release (which wasn't an **Episode**):

> The epic itself is basically about one man. You pass through a lot of
>   things, but you never get to look at it. [With ’Clone Wars’], we’re
>   not burdened by the mythological underpinnings. We get to go more
>   places,” Lucas said. “The story about Anakin Skywalker and his fall
>   into the dark side and redemption by his son, that’s finished. It was
>   started when he was 10, it ends when he died. There’s no more story to
>   tell. All that stuff is really not part of what this is.

<sub>([source](http://www.mtv.com/news/1592226/star-wars-mastermind-george-lucas-explains-why-he-pushed-anakin-skywalker-aside-for-clone-wars/))</sub>

And in 2008:

> Lucas: I've left pretty explicit instructions for there not to be any
>   more features. There will definitely be no Episodes VII - IX. That's
>   because there isn't any story. I mean, I never thought of anything!
>   And now there are novels about the events after Episode IV, which
>   isn't at all what I would have done with it.
>
> The Star Wars story is really the tragedy of Darth Vader. That is the
>   story. Once Vader dies, he doesn't come back to life, The Emperor
>   doesn't get cloned and Luke doesn't get married...

<sub>[source](http://millenniumfalcon.com/phpbb/viewtopic.php?t=8008)</sub>

So staying true to this vision, then yes, the *Star Wars* episodes should have ended with *Return of the Jedi*.

That said, Lucas did [have plans](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/113004/george-lucass-episode-vii/113022) for a seventh film when he sold to Disney, but its unknown what was in the scripts as they were [rejected by Disney](http://screenrant.com/star-wars-disney-george-lucas-deal-charlie-rose/).

Over the years, Lucas has said [many different things](http://whills.nu/7/) about the number of films he planned.

E.g. we were at 12 in Rolling Stone, June 12, 1980:

> So, I took the screenplay and divided it into three stories, and
>   rewrote the first one. As I was writing, I came up with some ideas for
>   a film about robots, with no humans in it. When I got to working on
>   the Wookiee, I thought of a film just about Wookiees, nothing else.
>   So, for a time, I had a couple of odd movies with just those
>   characters. Then, I had the other two films, which were essentially
>   split into three parts each, two trilogies. When the smoke cleared, I
>   said, 'This is really great. I'll do another trilogy that takes place
>   after this.' I had three trilogies of nine films, and then another
>   couple of odd films. Essentially, there were twelve films.

Comment: Nikolai, this question is 2 votes away from being closed as dupe (which it is) but I don't see your 2008 quote on that question. You could always stick it in aNOTHER answer over there :)